# urllib2.urlopen returns 404 for page that browser can return

Tags: python, debugging, urllib2

*Background: I'm working through the "Programming Collective Intelligence" book by Toby Segaran; specifically the Kayak API example from Chapter 5.*

I can **navigate with my browser (Chrome)** to the Kayak API results page (which is all XML) here:http://www.kayak.com/s/basic/flight?searchid=[searchidhere]&c=999&apimode=1&*sid*=[sessionidhere]&version=1

(I've previously created the session ID and the search ID successfully)

However, when I use

```
import urllib2
import xml.dom.minidom
url = 'http://www.kayak.com/s/basic/flight?searchid=NQnNrj&c=999&apimode=1&_sid_=19-y2WnyKIGm1FuaLfo2keV&version=1'
doc=xml.dom.minidom.parseString(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

I get the following response

```
[...discarded top bit of Traceback...]
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I've tested it with Python 2.5.4 and Python 2.7.1.  I'm almost 100% sure I've previously experimented with this and it worked successfully, and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Could anybody please help?  Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that the credentials for the link above timeout after 30 minutes and return a 404, which is why testing the link now returns a 404.  But when I entered it within that 30 minute window Chrome displays the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your problem is related to cookies.
Coincidentally, I usually browse the web without Javascript or Cookies enabled for sites on which I don't need them, and in that condition I clicked the link.

Without JS, Cookies and Referer information, I got a 404 page. After enabling all of those, I got a 'Search Expired' page. In order to confirm my theory, I enabled JS and Referer and clicked the link again, which led me to a 404 page again.

So, build an opener with HTTPCookieProcessor and the issue should be resolved.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Most probable explanation is that your search has been invalidated (outdated). Chrome might display data from the cache, try refreshing the page in chrome and see if results are still there.
Alternatively, web page might expect a previously saved cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you try the above query  in browser too, you will be getting a 404, just that they choose to format the 404 and display it. The request goes from 302 to 404 and urllib2 is doing the same.